# Cloudinary Image upload from django

Tags: python, django, cloudinary

I am trying to upload image/file to clodinary to get back the url using this code

```
    medical_file = request.FILES['medical_file']
    out = cloudinary.uploader.upload(File.open(medical_file, "rb"))
    url = out['url']
    medical_file_url = url
```

And I am successfully getting the url as well(I have printed that on my console)

But then I am getting this error of : `cloudinary.api.Error: Empty file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Cloudinary's [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_image_and_video_upload#data_uploading_options):

> In cases where images are uploaded by users of your Django application through a web form, you can pass the parameter of your Django's request.FILES to the upload method

So in your case, you can upload the file on the server-side by passing `request.FILES['medical_file']` directly to the upload method:

```
    out = cloudinary.uploader.upload(request.FILES['medical_file'])
```

Comment: Yes thats was the problem which i did ny removing the first line of code, thank anyway